# Symfony 4 route not found for a working Symfony project that I copied to a different server

Tags: php, symfony, routes, apache2

I am trying to copy a working Symfony project from one environment to the other environment. (The creator is currently not able to help me) It looks like I almost succeeded doing this, until I had to check the Symfony routing page. It gives me a 404 NOT FOUND page.

What I did is I copied the whole project from one environment to the other(which I setup by myself). Below are the files which I think are relevant for this problem. Let me know if I need to show different files in order to find a solution.

The page `host/(var/www/html/)project/public/` shows `the Welcome to Symfony!`-page.

Other `html` pages are running.

Navigating to the page that was setup using Symfony `host/project/public/MyPage` returns an HTTP 404 (Not found) error page.

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        <Directory "/var/www/html/project/public">
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
...
```

> MyController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/MyPage")
     */
    public function SubmitBootstrapAction(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
...
```

> /config/routes.yaml

```
#index:
#    path: /
#    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index
```

Comment: does apache2 mod rewrite is enabled ?

Comment: Wow, this actually makes the route work. `sudo a2enmod rewrite` enabled the rewrite module and now I am seeing a PHP error.

Comment: To increase performance, you should use FallbackResource instead of mod rewrite. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess rewrite engine is off

**Option1:** Old style, activate rewrite engine add the rewrite rules

```
    RewriteEngine on
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Option2: Recommanded**
As [described in documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html), you should no more use the rewrite engine. It's now recommanded to use the FallbackResource.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
    DirectoryIndex /index.php

    <Directory /var/www/project/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        FallbackResource /index.php   ###<==== Here
    </Directory>
```